# How to hide the menu items after click on them on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have an one page site (https://pizzabite.gr/) and my problem is in mobile version. When someone's select a category from the menu (for example if someone select the "menu", it will take him to a "menu" button). The problem is that the menu items (like "menu", "online" etc) hide this button. So if i want to appear this button i have to close the menu. 
My question is, if anyone knows, how to hide the menu on mobile version, after i click on menu item (like "menu") and don't hide the

Answer (score 0):

try using this code in your theme custom js or in your theme footer:

```
<script>
 if(jQuery(window).width() < 1240){
  jQuery('.menu-item').click(function(){
   jQuery(".responsive-menu-toggle").trigger("click");
  });
 }
</script>
```